# Render the Xml file having controls layout into HTML5 page

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html

I have the following xml file with the controls information to render into HTML page.
The contents are like:

```
  <control type="panel">
     <panel id="p1">
         <button id="b1">
            <value>TEST</value>
          </button>
          <textbox id="t1">
               <text>HELLO</text>
          </textbox>
      </panel>
   <control>
```

This has to rendered on the fly into a div with a panel containing one button and one textbox.The contents of xml are known only at runtime.It can be anything like only a button or a dropdown list information.How would one go about approaching this problem.A generic algorithm(probably using jquery) would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something generic, your XML would need to be generic or conformant to a convention along the lines of "XML to HTML form convention". I know of no such thing. :)

It seems easy enough to handle. Here's an example of how I'm handling your XML example.

```js
$(function() {
    
    // Data setup (I assume you'd be getting this from AJAX)
    var xml = '<control type="panel">' +
         '<panel id="p1">' +
             '<button id="b1">' +
                '<value>TEST</value>' +
              '</button>' +
              '<textbox id="t1">' +
                   '<text>HELLO</text>' +
              '</textbox>' +
          '</panel>' +
       '</control>';
    
    // Convert to jQuery XML object
    var xml = $($.parseXML(xml));
    
    // Set parent
    var parent = $('#control');
    
    // Handle elements
    xml.find('panel').children().each(function() {
        var tag = $(this)[0].tagName;
        switch (tag) {
            case 'button':
                parent.append('<button id="' +
                              $(this).attr('id') + '">' +
                              $(this).find('value').text() +
                              '</button>');
                break;
            case 'textbox':
                parent.append('<input type="text" id="' +
                              $(this).attr('id') +
                              '" value="' +
                              $(this).find('text').text() +
                              '" />');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="control"></div>
```

Of course, you could modify this as necessary, add new element handling, change the way it's added to the parent, etc. etc. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah it helped a lot..just wondering can there be a intermediate format/template like xml->"generic_template"->html  @BitwiseCreative

Comment: What if there are nested panels and menus.. Will the switch case approach work then @BitwiseCreative

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer :) Again, I don't think you could get a "generic" template, but there is XSLT (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT). It sounds like the layer you are referring to. I'm not familiar with it enough to provide an answer at this time with an XSLT solution.

Comment: I think the approach could work under any scenario, it would just require more logic and checking. I was just working with your example, and so didn't know what needed to be handled in a more complex XML version.